# May the owner of a towed car pick up the car from the lot its stored in without paying?

Tags: united-states, arizona

More specifically: if the car is not in a gated lot and is instead parked in a street-accessible parking lot, and there is no signage indicating trespass, what is preventing the car owner from just taking the car without paying?

Comment: Are we hypothesizing that the owners of the impound lot would not ask the owner to leave when they entered the property?  If they did, the owner would be guilty of trespassing, regardless of whether there are any signs prohibiting it.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, the assumption here is that there is no request by the property owners for the car owner to leave.

Comment: Somewhere there's a written record that the car was towed. Taking the car is not going to clear that record.